# LabVIEW: How do I break a loop when it matches a value in the array and returns the index

Tags: arrays, loops, combobox, labview

I have a combobox which has an array of Strings such as "Alice", "Bob",and "Charlie" and a string box where user can type. If user types "Bob"in the string box I want to print its index in the combobox, which is 1. Similarly if it is "Charlie" then I want to print "2". I would like to perform this with conditional exit with a for loop, but I am not sure how to return the index when the values are matched.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

1. Need to handle the case where the index is not found.
2. Need to put "String" outside the For Loop so the value is only read once instead of being read on every iteration.

[image]

The answer above is correct because you said in your question that you wanted to use the conditional terminal. There is a simpler way without the conditional terminal. I'm including the simpler way here for completeness. The picture below exactly what the picture above does but with a lot less wiring.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with this.
I converted Combo box to an array of strings and passed to a loop where I compared each instance of combo box with a string and if they are the same then exit then the last index gets printed.

[image: combobox]

Comment: One bug. You need to put the FPTerminal for "String" OUTSIDE the For Loop. Otherwise, you read the value on every iteration of the loop, which means someone could be typing on the front panel and change the value mid-way through processing the array.

Comment: Sorry -- 2 bugs... right now, you will return the wrong answer when the string is NOT in the array. You will return the index of the last element.

Comment: @user1296153, One remark, Although usually quite good answers Labview does not have that many active members here so some patience is advised before posting your own answer. Give it at least one day so that you give people around the globe the opportunity to answer. In Europe it was in the middle of the night when you posted.